# Solving the equation $\sin5x=16\sin^5x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve the equation $$\sin5x=16\sin^5x$$

I wrote \begin{align}\sin5x&=\sin(2x+3x)\\
&=\sin(2x)\cos(3x)+\cos(2x)\sin(3x)\end{align}

I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Do the same for $\sin (2x)$, $\cos (2x)$, $\cos(3x)$ and $\sin (3x)$ and then write $t=\sin x$.

You will get a polynomial in $t$ of degree 5 or less.

Comment: and how am i supposed to solve an equation of degree 5?

Comment: And what is this equation?

Comment: well You gave the method so you should make and solve the equation

Comment: SO WHAT IS THE QUESTION

Comment: @AbbasMurtaza that's not how it works. You have to make an effort to answer your own question, especially after receiving tips. No one is obligated to provide you with anything.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin5x=16\sin^5x$
$\sin3x\cos2x+\cos3x\sin2x=16\sin^5x$
$(3\sin x-4\sin^3x)(1-2\sin^2x)+2\sin x(4\cos^2x-3)\cos^2x=16\sin^5x$
$3\sin x(3-4\sin^2x)(1-2\sin^2x)+2\sin x(1-4\sin^2x)(1-2\sin^2x)=16\sin^4x\cdot\sin x$
$\sin x(3-10\sin^2x+2-10\sin^2x)=0$
$\sin x=0,\pm\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Factorize as follows

\begin{align}
& \sin5x - 16\sin^5x\\
= &\ (\sin x \cos4x + \cos x\sin 4x) -4\sin x(2\sin^2x)^2\\
=&\ \sin x(2\cos^22x -1 +4\cos^2  x\cos2x) - 4\sin x (1-\cos2x)^2\\
=&\ \sin x(4\cos^22x+2\cos2x-1 - 4(1-2\cos2x+\cos^22x)) \\
=&\ 5\sin x(2\cos2x-1) = 0
\end{align}

which leads to the solutions $x = n\pi,\>\pm\frac\pi6+n\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin5x-\sin x$$

$$=2\sin2x\cos3x$$

$$=4\sin x\cos x(4\cos^3x-3\cos x)$$

$$=4\sin x\cos^2x(4\cos^2x-3)$$

$$=4s(1-s^2)(4(1-s^2)-3)$$

$$=4s-20s^2+16s^5$$ where $s=\sin x$

So, we need $$0=5s-20s^2=5s(1-4s^2)=5\sin x(1-4\sin^2x)$$

If $1-4\sin^2x=0,\sin^2x=\dfrac14,\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x=\dfrac12$

What if $\sin x=0?$

Answer (score 0):

Note that\begin{align}\sin(5x)&=\sin(x)\cos(4x)+\cos(x)\sin(4x)\\&=\sin(x)\bigl(1-2\sin^2(2x)\bigr)+2\cos(x)\cos(2x)\sin(2x)\\&=\sin(x)\bigl(1-8\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)\bigr)+2\cos(x)\bigl(1-2\sin^2(x)\bigr)2\sin(x)\cos(x)\\&=\sin(x)\bigl(1-8\sin^2(x)\bigl(1-\sin^2(x)\bigr)\bigr)+4\cos^2(x)\bigl(1-2\sin^2(x)\bigr)2\sin(x)\\&=\sin(x)\bigl(1-8\sin^2(x)\bigl(1-\sin^2(x)\bigr)\bigr)+4\bigl(1-\sin^2(x)\bigr)\bigl(1-2\sin^2(x)\bigr)2\sin(x)\\&=5\sin(x)-20\sin^3(x)+16\sin^5(x)\end{align}and that therefore\begin{align}\sin(5x)=16\sin^5(x)&\iff5\sin(x)-20\sin^3(x)=0\\&\iff\sin(x)=0\vee\sin^2(x)=\frac12.\end{align}